# eosio cleos, transfer commands with --url is unsecured?

Tags: ethereum, eos

Is this command unsecured?

```
./cleos --url https://eos.greymass.com transfer from to "3 EOS" "memo"
```

Is my private key still secure?

Comment: you should probably elaborate what do you mean secure/unsecured here

Comment: I mean, my private keys under secure?

Answer (score 0):

Your private key is used to sign transactions. The signed transaction is what is transferred over the internet. Your private key is secured as long as the host machine that's storing the private key is secured.

Answer (score 0):

Your private key is used only during `sign_transaction` which is a wallet operation. You cannot perform a wallet operation using third party/block producer API. You have to run `keosd` locally in your system to perform wallet operations.

To perform `./cleos --url https://eos.greymass.com transfer from to "3 EOS" "memo"` action, you have to make your wallet imported with keys and it should be unlocked. This should done locally in your system.

In short, your keys are secure while using `./cleos --url https://eos.greymass.com`